# Deployment automation in AWS servers

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, deployment, automation, remote-server

Deployment script which have to run on remote aws linux machines. But i got problem while tomcat start, here is the code and error

1.`sh /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/bin/shutdown.sh`

2.`scp -i /tmp/Keys/*****.pem fedora@**.**.**.***:/opt/artifacts/appedo.war /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps`

3.`sh /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/bin/startup.sh`

To run on remote linux machine:

```
ssh username@**.**.**.*** 'bash -s' < /opt/scripts/deploytest.sh
```

1&2 working fine. While running 3rd, error came like this:

```
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/logs/catalina.out’: Permission denied
/var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/bin/catalina.sh: line 387: 
/var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

Please share me your thoughts.... (one way is giving full permissions to catalina.out will solve the issue but as for our needs it has to have 644 permissions only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubleshooted the issue myself. 
Destination machine sudoers file changed a bit as below

sudo visudo => commented Defaults requiretty.

changed 3rd line to <=> sudo sh /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/bin/startup.sh, then it is working fine.